# get values based on date time

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database

What i want to achieve is the following:-

1- Get the records that have the current date (todays) from the database.
2- if the database doesnt have records from today i want it to get it from the day before.
3- if the day before does not have any records i want it to get them from the day before that and so on.

```
try
    {
        string date = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        conn.Open();
        //string str = "insert into Table1 (title , date_ ,www, cat) values  (' " + TextBox1.Text + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text + "')";
        ////string str = "INSERT INTO Table1  (title,date_,www ) values ('ddddddd','aaaaaaa','qqqqqq')";


        string str =

            //"SELECT   from table1  WHERE  cat = 1 and datee='" + date + "'ORDER BY datee";
        "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE cat = 1 and datee = @dt ORDER BY datee DESC ";



        SqlCommand objcmd = new SqlCommand(str, conn);

        objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", date);

        SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(objcmd);


        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        da1.Fill(dt);




        //DataRow dr = new DataRow();
        //DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];

        int id = 1;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            if (id == 1)
            {
                    ll1.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                    l1.ImageUrl = @"photo\" + dr[1].ToString() + @".jpg";


            }
            if (id == 2)
            {
                ll2.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                l2.ImageUrl = @"photo\" + dr[1].ToString() + @".jpg";
            }
            if (id == 3)
            {
                ll3.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                l3.ImageUrl = @"photo\" + dr[1].ToString() + @".jpg";
            }
            if (id == 4)
            {
                ll4.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                l4.ImageUrl = @"photo\" + dr[1].ToString() + @".jpg";
            }
            if (id == 5)
            {
                ll5.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                l5.ImageUrl = @"photo\" + dr[1].ToString() + @".jpg";
            }
            if (id == 6)
            {
                ll6.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                l6.ImageUrl = @"photo\" + dr[1].ToString() + @".jpg";
            }
            if (id == 7)
            {
                ll7.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                l7.ImageUrl = @"photo\" + dr[1].ToString() + @".jpg";
            }
            if (id == 8)
            {
                ll8.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                l8.ImageUrl = @"photo\" + dr[1].ToString() + @".jpg";
            }
            if (id == 9)
            {
                ll9.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                l9.ImageUrl = @"photo\" + dr[1].ToString() + @".jpg";
            }
            if (id == 10)
            {
                ll10.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                l10.ImageUrl = @"photo\" + dr[1].ToString() + @".jpg";
            }
            if (id == 11)
            {
                ll11.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                l11.ImageUrl = @"photo\" + dr[1].ToString() + @".jpg";
            }
            if (id == 12)
            {
                ll12.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                l12.ImageUrl = @"photo\" + dr[1].ToString() + @".jpg";
            }
            if (id == 13)
            {
                ll13.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                l13.ImageUrl = @"photo\" + dr[1].ToString() + @".jpg";
            }
            if (id == 14)
            {
                ll14.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                l14.ImageUrl = @"photo\" + dr[1].ToString() + @".jpg";
            }
            if (id == 15)
            {
                ll15.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                l16.ImageUrl = @"photo\" + dr[1].ToString() + @".jpg";
            }
            if (id == 16)
            {
                ll16.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                l16.ImageUrl = @"photo\" + dr[1].ToString() + @".jpg";
            }
            if (id == 17)
            {
                ll17.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                l17.ImageUrl = @"photo\" + dr[1].ToString() + @".jpg";
            }
            if (id == 18)
            {
                ll18.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                l18.ImageUrl = @"photo\" + dr[1].ToString() + @".jpg";
            }
            if (id == 19)
            {
                ll19.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                l19.ImageUrl = @"photo\" + dr[1].ToString() + @".jpg";
            }
            if (id == 20)
            {
                ll20.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                l20.ImageUrl = @"photo\" + dr[1].ToString() + @".jpg";
            }
            if (id == 21)
            {
                ll21.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                l21.ImageUrl = @"photo\" + dr[1].ToString() + @".jpg";
            }
            if (id == 22)
            {
                ll22.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                l22.ImageUrl = @"photo\" + dr[1].ToString() + @".jpg";
            }
            if (id == 23)
            {
                ll23.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                l23.ImageUrl = @"photo\" + dr[1].ToString() + @".jpg";
            }
            if (id == 24)
            {
                ll24.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                l24.ImageUrl = @"photo\" + dr[1].ToString() + @".jpg";
            }
            id = id + 1;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblError.Text = "فشل في إحظار الأخبار";
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: `date before` does it mean that you want to get all data. Please clarify.

Comment: llx and lx really need to be arrays. Your code could fit on one page that way and would be way more readable.

Comment: @saravanan  yes all the data from the date before if there is no data from today

Comment: @coderoaq: You can try this in 2 ways, either run a query and get the data for the date. if nothing is obtained, re-run another query and get the data before. Or else you can use an SP to get things done at the database end. 
If there is no date input, you can just remove it from the filter clause thereby getting all the data, not just today's data.

Comment: What if the date before is empty as well?

Comment: Why have you unaccepted my answer? Please elaborate. Didn't it work for you?

Comment: @AdamFridental no i didn't there was an error near "join"

Comment: @coderoaq You're right, it shouldn't be 'JOIN' but 'UNION' - I've updated my answer, test it now.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you update your SQL query to do your work and avoid 2 database hits, you can do it with something like this:

```
string str = 
    "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE cat = 1 and datee = @dt ORDER BY datee DESC " +
    "UNION SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE cat = 1 and datee < @dt AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE cat = 1 and datee = @dt) = 0 ORDER BY datee DESC";
```

You can see that I join all results before the date to the results if the count of those results is 0 (meaning if nothing was selected, select those prior to that date)

Comment: Even better, encapsulate the query as a stored procedure. If your query is exposed to the outside world, you have the posability of an injection attack: CREATE PROC myOlderDateCat @ParamLastDate AS above select. Also dont use select *, return only the rows you want. Drag it into a LinqToDB class. Bind it to a grid and almost all your work will be done for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
   int id = 1;//???????
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        if (id == 1)//???????
        {
                ll1.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                l1.ImageUrl = @"photo\" + dr[1].ToString() + @".jpg";
        }
```

you always check ID for ID=1
instead of that use this :

```
if ( dr[1] == id)
{
...
}
id++
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code to get all the items from entire first day that has any rows (going backwards in time). This assumes SQL Server 2005 or higher (you didn't say what DBMS & version you're using, please do so!):

```
WITH Data AS (
   SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
      *
   FROM dbo.table1
   WHERE
      cat = 1
      AND datee >= DateAdd(day, -5, @dt)
   ORDER BY
      Convert(date, datee) DESC
)
SELECT *
FROM Data
ORDER BY datee DESC
;
```

If you can order the rows in your front end (and you probably should) then you don't need the extra, outer query. Using this `TOP 1 WITH TIES` syntax you cannot add more expressions to the inner `ORDER BY` clause because this would change what is selected.

You also should probably select only the desired columns rather than everything from the table.